# Access the AWS RDS describe db snapshot API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-rds, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to access the aws rds api to describe db snapshots. I plan on having this be parsed so that I can list all the available aws snapshots by id using groovy. However the biggest problem I am having is getting the api in the first place. I took a look at AWS's reference on this topic but I can't seem to figure out how to generate the pre-signed portion of the request with credentials. I am not sure why that part is even necessary. Why can't the user authenticate using the Access key ID and the Secret access key combination?

The reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBSnapshots.html

The section with the issue:

```
https://rds.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
   ?Action=DescribeDBSnapshots
   &IncludePublic=false
   &IncludeShared=true
   &MaxRecords=100
   &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
   &SignatureVersion=4
   &Version=2014-09-01
   &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
   &X-Amz-Credential=AKIADQKE4SARGYLE/20140421/us-west-2/rds/aws4_request
   &X-Amz-Date=20140421T194732Z
   &X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
   &X-Amz-Signature=4aa31bdcf7b5e00dadffbd6dc8448a31871e283ffe270e77890e15487354bcca
```

Answer (score 0):

If groovy is a hard requirement, I'd look into something like this https://grails.org/plugin/aws-sdk

If you're comfortable with Java, I'd say use the official AWS-SDK

If you're scripting this out, you could also use the official AWS cli tool and do something like

`aws rds describe-db-snapshots [OPTIONS]`

From there you could use a tool like `jq` to zero-in and parse out your specific ID's. You can find more documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html).

The way you'd authorize with the SDK is either through environment variables (the preferred approach) or probably hardcoding your KEY and SECRET (big no no)

Comment: I am using this api call as a part of a Jenkins pipeline parameter. I am not sure how much of a choice I have. I am using the aws api for stages of the pipeline. I will have to look into aws sdk as you've suggested as an alternative.

Comment: There's literally a Jenkins Plugin if you have admin access to Jenkins
https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-java-sdk/

If not, you can always install it on the fly, but that might add some time to the your pipeline.

Don't try to a direct REST call, that v4 signature is a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than trying to directly communicate with the API directly you should make use of the built in wrappers that AWS provide.

If you're accessing this with a supported programmatic language take a look at the [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). There are currently officially supported libraries for:

- C++
- Go
- Java
- JavaScript
- .NET
- NodeJS
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby

If your language of choice is not covered there may be a third party solution already. Alternatively take a look at the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to resolve your problem.

For your specific action [describe-db-snapshots](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html) you can get a list of all IDs by running the below, then parse as JSON.

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query 'DBSnapshots[*].DBSnapshotIdentifier' --format json
```